# JavaScript - how to toggle setInterval

Tags: javascript, vue.js, setinterval

in my Vue app I am trying to toggle between two Intervals, depends on the switcher flag (true or false) I want to display "This is first interval" or "This is second interval". My method:

```
data() {
   return {
     switcher: false
   }
},

methods: {
 switchInterval() {
   this.switcher = !this.switcher;
   if(this.switcher) {
       let firstInterval = setInterval(() => {
         console.log('This is first interval')
       }, 1000)
    if(this.switcher === false) clearInterval(firstInterval);
     }

      if(!this.switcher) {
         let secondInterval = setInterval(() =>{
             console.log('This is second interval')
          }, 1000);

      if(this.chatSwitch === true) clearInterval(secondInterval);
 }
}
```

Could anybody help me with this?

Comment: you save the callbacks in variables and then pass to setinterval based on switcher value

Comment: @Asadali but where do I stop the previous one? I want them to toggle

Comment: Why use two intervals rather than a single interval that conditionally does what you want? Are you trying to reset the interval timer when the switch occurs?

Comment: @rottenbanana did the code solve your problem?

Comment: Your code have some issue as you are checking `if (this.switcher === false)` inside `if (this.switcher)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
toggleInterval() {
      let handler;
      this.switcher = !this.switcher;

      if (this.switcher) {
        handler = () => {
          console.log('This is first interval');
        };
      } else {
        handler = () => {
          console.log('This is first interval');
        };
      }
      clearInterval(this.intervalId);
      this.intervalId = setInterval(handler, 1000);
},
```

[info on setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Comment: What is the this.intervalId?